# SQL - Use CASE for WHERE NOT EXIST condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to modify the below code using a CASE WHEN scenario where I want to add a new column to identify records returned as 'BAD' for the results returned in the below query. Else 'GOOD'

```
select distinct

LFA1.LIFNR as Vendor_Number,
Lfa1.name1 as Vendor_Name,
LFA1.KTOKK as Account_Group,
T077Y.TXT30 as Account_Group_Name

from dgSAP_PRD.dbo.LFA1 as LFA1
inner join dgSAP_PRD.dbo.T077Y as T077Y on LFA1.KTOKK = T077Y.KTOKK
where not exists (select * 
                  from dgSAP_PRD.dbo.adr6 as adr6 
                  where LFA1.ADRNR = adr6.ADDRNUMBER and adr6.PERSNUMBER = '') 

and T077Y.SPRAS = 'E' and LFA1.KTOKK = 'Z012' and LFA1.SPERQ not in ('99', '06', '07', '11','10','12')
```

I tried to add the case when for the query and sub-query as per below but I'm getting errors, please help.

```
select distinct

LFA1.LIFNR as Vendor_Number,
Lfa1.name1 as Vendor_Name,
LFA1.KTOKK as Account_Group,
T077Y.TXT30 as Account_Group_Name

from dgSAP_PRD.dbo.LFA1 as LFA1
inner join dgSAP_PRD.dbo.T077Y as T077Y on LFA1.KTOKK = T077Y.KTOKK
CASE WHEN not exists ((select * 
                  from dgSAP_PRD.dbo.adr6 as adr6 
                  where LFA1.ADRNR = adr6.ADDRNUMBER and adr6.PERSNUMBER = '') 

and T077Y.SPRAS = 'E' and LFA1.KTOKK = 'Z012' and LFA1.SPERQ not in ('99', '06', '07', '11','10','12'))

THEN 'BAD' ELSE 'GOOD' END AS DQ_FLAG
```

Comment: Please update your question it is not clear what you are asking for.  Straight out it does not look like you need case in where clause.  If you need good/bad value that would go in select statement, not in where clause.

Comment: Hey @Brad, I want to add a new column to denote whether the data is GOOD or BAD. The results of my original returned query would all fall under BAD. Then any data that exists in ADR6 AND LFA1 will be considered GOOD (i.e. similar to an inner join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to select records that exist as well as those that don't. You can't select records which don't exist. The best you can do is join on a table that might contain records you want, and determine whether you're getting NULL for those records:

```
select distinct

LFA1.LIFNR as Vendor_Number,
Lfa1.name1 as Vendor_Name,
LFA1.KTOKK as Account_Group,
T077Y.TXT30 as Account_Group_Name,
( CASE WHEN adr6.ADDRNUMBER IS NULL THEN 'BAD' ELSE 'GOOD' END ) AS status

from dgSAP_PRD.dbo.LFA1 as LFA1
inner join dgSAP_PRD.dbo.T077Y as T077Y on LFA1.KTOKK = T077Y.KTOKK
inner join dgSAP_PRD.dbo.adr6 as adr6 on (LFA1.ADRNR = adr6.ADDRNUMBER and adr6.PERSNUMBER = '') 

and T077Y.SPRAS = 'E' and LFA1.KTOKK = 'Z012' and LFA1.SPERQ not in ('99', '06', '07', '11','10','12')
```

Comment: Thanks @kmoser, I want to select records where it exist in LFA1 but not in ADR6 with the given condition as 'BAD' and if it exists in both then I want them to be 'GOOD'. Your code works for all the GOOD records however I'm not getting any 'BAD' as I should have these data

Comment: Actually I used UNION between your logic and my previous code and it worked. THanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an information with select clause, show `'GOOD'` or `'BAD'`, you can use `LEFT JOIN`, and in the select section, you can use the `CASE WHEN`.

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN table2.id_tbl1 is not null then 'A' 
         else 'B' 
       end AS result 
FROM   table1 
       left join table2 
              on table1.id_tbl1 = table2.id_tbl1--where conditions
```